# Conditional If Statement: If value in row starts with letter in string … set another column with some corresponding value

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the 'Field_Type' column filled with strings and I want to derive the values in the 'Units' column using an if statement.

So Units shows the desired result. Essentially I want to call out what type of activity is occurring.

I tried to do this using my code below but it won't run (please see screen shot below for error). Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Please have a look at the table]

````
create_table['Units'] = pd.np.where(create_table['Field_Name'].str.startswith("W"), "MW",
pd.np.where(create_table['Field_Name'].str.contains("R"), "MVar",
pd.np.where(create_table['Field_Name'].str.contains("V"), "Per Unit")))```

ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
````

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to define your conditionals, then use `apply` on the dataframe and pass the funtion

```
def unit_mapper(row):
    if row['Field_Type'].startswith('W'):
        return 'MW'
    elif 'R' in row['Field_Type']:
        return 'MVar'
    elif 'V' in row['Field_Type']:
        return 'Per Unit'
    else:
        return 'N/A'
```

And then

```
create_table['Units'] = create_table.apply(unit_mapper, axis=1)
```

Comment: the error :("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 0):

In your text you talk about `Field_Type` but you are using `Field_Name` in your example. Which one is good ?

You want to do something like:

```py
create_table[create_table['Field_Type'].str.startwith('W'), 'Units'] = 'MW'
create_table[create_table['Field_Type'].str.startwith('R'), 'Units'] = 'MVar'
create_table[create_table['Field_Type'].str.startwith('V'), 'Units'] = 'Per Unit'
```